# how to create a table view with autoheight for each row

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am having a tableview and I'm loading different tableviewcells how can I make the table view row height to adjust based on the each tableviewcells content height

for example some tableview cell height could be 80 and some could be 120

and sometimes the cell height can reduce or increase based on the label at bottom appears or not..

How may I do this in tableview ?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve dynamic cell height with the help of autodimension. In viewDidLayout add couple of line of code. Don't provide static height at heightForRowAtIndexPath.

`tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
 tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100`

Now the only thing you have to do is design cell in such a way that the content pushes the view outward ultimately the cell expands or contracts (in terms of height). For this provide top and bottom constraint in subview associated to the view in cell which will determine the height of the cell.
[image: Provide top and bottom constraint]

Comment: Let me try and get back to you

Comment: are you sure height will auto change if we set estimated row height to 100 ? what if the cell size is just 40 ro 140 will it let occupy

Comment: Yes height will change according to the content i.e 40 or 400, estimated row height doesn't affect the dynamic height but you must set the estimated so that it can be used by the cell in case the dynamic height can't be calculated. You can follow https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells this tutorial.

Comment: One more question able self sizing tableview ...not tableview cell... lets say table height has been fixed to be 400 . and I have tableviewcell height exactly 100 .. if I am showing 4 rows then height of the tableview is completely occupied .. if more than 4 then I will have scrolling to see the other records that are not visible .. but if I have less than 4 records then ... table heights occupied by tableview cell is 300.100px is extra height will be there.. is it possible that I can make the table view to shrink to 300 px.. because I don't want empty spaces kinda self sizing tableview height

Comment: Yes you can do it simply by: `tableView.frame = CGRect(x: tableView.frame.origin.x, y: tableView.frame.origin.y, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: tableView.contentSize.height) and
tableView.reloadData()` in viewDidAppear and in viewDidLayoutSubviews. If you find issue try relo